# Mongodb primary node not Resolved in Debezium Kafka Connect — Docker Compose

Tags: mongodb, hostname, bitnami, kafka, connect

i have this docker compose file, that contains `bitnami/mongodb` containers for creating a replica set. and I've used `zookeeper`, `kafka` & `debezium-connector` for monitoring my mongodb replica set.

```
version: '2.2'
services:
    mongodb-primary:
        hostname: mongodb-primary
        image: 'bitnami/mongodb:latest'
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        environment:
            - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_NAME=rs0
            - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=primary
            - MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD=another_root
            - MONGODB_DATABASE=genomics
            - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY=replicasetkey123
            - MONGODB_USERNAME=genomics_user
            - MONGODB_PASSWORD=another
            - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb-primary
        volumes:
            - 'mongodb_master_data:/bitnami'
    mongodb-secondary:
        hostname: mongodb-secondary
        image: 'bitnami/mongodb:latest'
        depends_on:
            - mongodb-primary
        environment:
            - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_NAME=rs0
            - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=secondary
            - MONGODB_PRIMARY_HOST=mongodb-primary
            - MONGODB_PRIMARY_PORT_NUMBER=27017
            - MONGODB_PRIMARY_ROOT_PASSWORD=another_root
            - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY=replicasetkey123
            - MONGODB_USERNAME=genomics_user
            - MONGODB_PASSWORD=another
            - MONGODB_DATABASE=genomics
            - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb-secondary
    mongodb-arbiter:
        hostname: mongodb-arbiter
        image: 'bitnami/mongodb:latest'
        depends_on:
            - mongodb-primary
        environment:
            - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_NAME=rs0
            - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=arbiter
            - MONGODB_PRIMARY_HOST=mongodb-primary
            - MONGODB_PRIMARY_PORT_NUMBER=27017
            - MONGODB_PRIMARY_ROOT_PASSWORD=another_root
            - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY=replicasetkey123
            - MONGODB_USERNAME=genomics_user
            - MONGODB_PASSWORD=another
            - MONGODB_DATABASE=genomics
            - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb-arbiter
    debezium_connect:
        image: debezium/connect:0.7
        ports:
            - 8083:8083
        environment:
            - BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092
            - GROUP_ID=1
            - CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs
            - OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets
        links:
            - kafka
            - mongodb-primary
    kafka:
        image: debezium/kafka:0.7
        environment:
            KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
            KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
            KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
            ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
            KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "topic-jhipster:1:1"
        ports:
            - 9092:9092
        links:
            - zookeeper
    zookeeper:
        image: debezium/zookeeper:0.7
        ports:
            - 2181:2181
            - 2888:2888
            - 3888:3888
    consul:
        image: consul:0.9.3
        command: consul agent -dev -ui -client 0.0.0.0
        ports:
            - 8300:8300
            - 8500:8500
            - 8600:8600
    consul-config-loader:
        image: jhipster/consul-config-loader:v0.2.2
        volumes:
            - ./central-server-config:/config
        environment:
            - INIT_SLEEP_SECONDS=5
            - CONSUL_URL=consul
            - CONSUL_PORT=8500
        # Uncomment to load configuration into Consul from a Git repository
        # as configured in central-server-config/git2consul.json
        # Also set SPRING_CLOUD_CONSUL_CONFIG_FORMAT=files on your apps
        #    - CONFIG_MODE=git

volumes:
    mongodb_master_data:
        driver: local

# networks:
#     app-tier:
#         driver: bridge
```

so i started this file by

```
docker-compose -f app.yaml up
```

and now `debezium_connect` image is ready for accepting a mongodb connector properties:

```
{
    "name": "run-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class" : "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector",
        "tasks.max" : "1",
        "mongodb.hosts" : "rs0/mongodb-primary:27017",
        "mongodb.name" : "genomics",
        "mongodb.user" : "genomics_user",
        "mongodb.password" : "another",
        "database.whitelist" : "inventory",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers" : "kafka:9092"
    }
}
```

which is done by using this command:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H  "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/ -d @register-mongodb.json
```

in which `register-mongodb.json` content is displayed above.
but after curling this error comes out of debezium_connect:

```
2018-06-05 15:49:35,080 INFO   MongoDB|genomics|disc  No server chosen by ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary} from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=mongodb-primary:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='genomics_user', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}}, caused by {com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18: 'Authentication failed.' on server mongodb-primary:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Authentication failed.", "code" : 18, "codeName" : "AuthenticationFailed", "operationTime" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 1528213769, "i" : 1 } }, "$clusterTime" : { "clusterTime" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 1528213769, "i" : 1 } }, "signature" : { "hash" : { "$binary" : "vSvTuw+hQCycX/rSliCcxWEh1BM=", "$type" : "00" }, "keyId" : { "$numberLong" : "6563606422322413569" } } } }}}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out   [org.mongodb.driver.cluster]
2018-06-05 15:50:05,081 ERROR  MongoDB|genomics|disc  Error while reading the 'shards' collection in the 'config' database: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=mongodb-primary:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='genomics_user', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}}, caused by {com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18: 'Authentication failed.' on server mongodb-primary:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Authentication failed.", "code" : 18, "codeName" : "AuthenticationFailed", "operationTime" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 1528213799, "i" : 1 } }, "$clusterTime" : { "clusterTime" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 1528213799, "i" : 1 } }, "signature" : { "hash" : { "$binary" : "tk+Fd4ytnt/O8TMDyG43h79fnkk=", "$type" : "00" }, "keyId" : { "$numberLong" : "6563606422322413569" } } } }}}]   [io.debezium.connector.mongodb.ReplicaSetDiscovery]
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=mongodb-primary:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='genomics_user', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}}, caused by {com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18: 'Authentication failed.' on server mongodb-primary:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Authentication failed.", "code" : 18, "codeName" : "AuthenticationFailed", "operationTime" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 1528213799, "i" : 1 } }, "$clusterTime" : { "clusterTime" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 1528213799, "i" : 1 } }, "signature" : { "hash" : { "$binary" : "tk+Fd4ytnt/O8TMDyG43h79fnkk=", "$type" : "00" }, "keyId" : { "$numberLong" : "6563606422322413569" } } } }}}]
    at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.createTimeoutException(BaseCluster.java:377)
    at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.selectServer(BaseCluster.java:104)
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.<init>(ClusterBinding.java:75)
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.<init>(ClusterBinding.java:71)
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding.getReadConnectionSource(ClusterBinding.java:63)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:402)
    at com.mongodb.operation.ListDatabasesOperation.execute(ListDatabasesOperation.java:102)
    at com.mongodb.operation.ListDatabasesOperation.execute(ListDatabasesOperation.java:54)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:836)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:823)
    at com.mongodb.OperationIterable.iterator(OperationIterable.java:47)
    at com.mongodb.ListDatabasesIterableImpl.iterator(ListDatabasesIterableImpl.java:57)
    at com.mongodb.MappingIterable.iterator(MappingIterable.java:36)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoUtil.contains(MongoUtil.java:181)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoUtil.contains(MongoUtil.java:170)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoUtil.onDatabase(MongoUtil.java:114)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoUtil.onCollection(MongoUtil.java:129)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoUtil.onCollectionDocuments(MongoUtil.java:148)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.ReplicaSetDiscovery.getReplicaSets(ReplicaSetDiscovery.java:67)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.ReplicaSetMonitorThread.run(ReplicaSetMonitorThread.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-06-05 15:50:05,082 INFO   MongoDB|genomics|disc  Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out   [org.mongodb.driver.cluster]
```

is there any problem with my network? i think debezium_connect can't see mongodb-primary, so it can't authenticate..

you can delete existing "run-connector" by this command:

```
curl -X DELETE localhost:8083/connectors/run-connector/
```

i can authenticate into mongo-replica-set by other third party tools like `robo3t` or another application which i wrote myself. but can't do it with  `debezium_connect` in docker network. also should note that the application i wrote myself has no problem connecting to mongodb in the docker network.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by an authentication error. This exception was thrown:

> Command failed with error 18: 'Authentication failed.' on server mongodb-primary:27017

Please re-check your username and password again.

Comment: yes.. it's not a networking issue... any container can see that container.. it's a debezium authentication issue i think..  i checked user/pass many times..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have intiated MongoDB to have the necessary privileges for your user? Please crosscheck with http://debezium.io/docs/connectors/mongodb/#setting-up-mongodb